# How can i set the plugin's option in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I use NERDTree plugin.
Now i want to set the 'NERETreeHijackNetrw' option to value 0.
what should i write into my .vimrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try

```
let NERDTreeHijackNetrw = 0
```

?